# What is the proper way to configure SMTPAppender in log4j?

Tags: java, smtp, log4j

I'm trying to configure log4j to use the `SMTPAppender` but I keep getting relay access denied errors.  I get this error when executing my code on my laptop AND straight from my shared hosting environment.

Here's the relevant config:

```
#CONFIGURE SMTP
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=mydomain.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=myuser
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=mypw
log4j.appender.email.From=myuser@mydomain.com
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.email.EvaluatorClass=TriggerLogEvent
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```

If I switch to `log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=mail.mydomain.com` instead then I get authentication errors.  My hosting is on DreamHost so bonus points if anyone has set up log4j `SMTPAppender` using a DreamHost email account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I just had the properties all wrong.  Should be:

```
#CONFIGURE SMTP
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=mail.mydomain.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=myuser@mydomain.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=mypw
log4j.appender.email.From=myuser@mydomain.com
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.email.EvaluatorClass=TriggerLogEvent
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```

Comment: This gives me: _java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TriggerLogEvent_. Is this for an old version of log4j?

Comment: Turns out that `TriggerLogEvent` is a downloadable class that you can use if you need to log levels other than ERROR. More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8170636/24874

Answer (score 0):

SMTPHost should point to your mail server (so, `mail.mydomain.com` for Dreamhost).  Can you send mail manually if you telnet to port 25 and pass credentials by hand?