# Java: operator notifications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, notifications, monitoring, administration

We need to monitor application stability. On of the part of this process is notifying operators (via xmpp, email, ...) about the potential issues in the business process.

That tools is more preferable for this kind of activity? Is it a good idea to use monitoring solutions like [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/), or maybe some advanced java libraries exist for this?

Comment: I have used nagios a few times. It's adequate.

Comment: You can use Log4j SMTPAppender tosend monitors. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306212/use-log4j-to-send-email-reports

Comment: Is this something the application can discover itself, or must it be discovered from the "outside"?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen The Application detects issues by itself.
But notifications to user can be send by outside application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the program can discover issues itself, you could use the facilites available with a modern logging framework.  You code against the slf4j API and use a logging backend configured to handle e.g. error messages special.

You then just have to have such a snippet in your code:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
   log.error("FooBar processing failed", e);
}
```

This generic approach at compile time can then do one or more of the following at runtime:

- Log to a special file.
- Send a Syslog message to another machine
- Send an email to a predefined recipient with the error message and the stack trace.
- Send an instant message to a Jabber account (which can then be forwarded to a MSN or a Yahoo account)
- Write a row in a database

or you can write your own code doing what you need to have done.

Comment: Can you advise XMPPAdapter for logging? I have not to find quick solution in this case.

Comment: send message to user(s) (or private chatroom)

Comment: Try.  It should be very simple to create a sample program.

Comment: unfortunately I'm looking for existing solutions, not the way how to realize XMPPAdapter from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You could use log4j [SMTPAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html) to send eMails to operators for selected error-level log - entries that require analization of an issue.

For log based monitoring you might want to check [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Log4J is useful for monitoring events (Ex: something has crashed, takes too long to complete, etc)

If you need realtime monitoring you should use JMX beans.
This technology is designed for monitoring the activity of the applications.
With this technology you could notify when some threshold is breached. (queue is filled by 75%)

There are several tools to connect to JMX enabled systems and to monitor them.