# How do you send an email in a java program that sends the recipient what the console displays?

Tags: java, eclipse, email, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a Selenium WebDriver which after it is run it makes a table in the console that says which apps fails or passes my test. I want to be able to send this table to someone after it is run. Here is my code for the table part of my program. It does successfully make the table, I just never sent an email in a java program before. Thanks in advance.

```
        String to = "abcd@gmail.com";
        String from = "efg@gmail.com";
        String host = "localhost";
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

            message.setSubject("TEST RESULTS");

            //Something needs to go here I think
        }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I do have JavaMail and Java Activation Framework installed and in the classpath

Comment: `String to = "abcd$gmail.com";` shouldn't this be `String to = "abcd@gmail.com";`

Comment: @Chris yes, thanks for seeing my typo, that wasn't the main problem but I would've had a problem with that when I got the rest working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a class to send email using gmail which may work for you. You need to give it your gmail username and password.

```
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class GoogleMail {
    private GoogleMail() {
    }

    /**
     * Send email using GMail SMTP server.
     *
     * @param username GMail username
     * @param password GMail password
     * @param recipientEmail TO recipient
     * @param title title of the message
     * @param message message to be sent
     * @throws AddressException if the email address parse failed
     * @throws MessagingException if the connection is dead or not in the connected state or if the message is not a MimeMessage
     */
    public static void send(final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String title, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        GoogleMail.Send(username, password, recipientEmail, "", title, message);
    }

    /**
     * Send email using GMail SMTP server.
     *
     * @param username GMail username
     * @param password GMail password
     * @param recipientEmail TO recipient
     * @param ccEmail CC recipient. Can be empty if there is no CC recipient
     * @param title title of the message
     * @param message message to be sent
     * @throws AddressException if the email address parse failed
     * @throws MessagingException if the connection is dead or not in the connected state or if the message is not a MimeMessage
     */
    public static void send(final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String ccEmail, String title, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

        // Get a Properties object
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

        /*
        If set to false, the QUIT command is sent and the connection is immediately closed. If set 
        to true (the default), causes the transport to wait for the response to the QUIT command.

        ref :   http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html
                http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5205249
                smtpsend.java - demo program from javamail
        */
        props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        // -- Create a new message --
        final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username + "@gmail.com"));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

        if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
        }

        msg.setSubject(title);
        msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

        t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());      
        t.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend collecting your output in a stringbuffer and use log4j. Configure a log4j smtp appender and log your results. Log4j will take care of mailing your result.
Look here: [Using log4j to send email reports via the SMTPAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306212/using-log4j-to-send-email-reports-via-the-smtpappender)