# Catch RuntimeExceptions in Java application and send them via email

Tags: logging, log4j, daemon, runtimeexception, jsvc

I'm starting my app on Linux server with a command like this

```
/usr/local/bin/jsvc \
    -home /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_111 \
    -cp /opt/myapp/myapp.jar:/opt/myapp/lib/* \
    -user myappuser \
    -outfile /opt/myapp/out.log \
    -errfile /opt/myapp/error.log \
    -pidfile /opt/myapp/myapp.pid \
    com.example.MyApp
```

I'm using `log4j` for logging in my app and it has own configuration described in `log4j.properties` which is located inside `myapp.jar`.

I want to be able to catch any exception which happens in the app and to send it to me via email. I have configured `org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender` in `log4j.properties` for that purpose.

But currently `RuntimeException`, like `NullPointerException` are just printed to `stderr` which `jsvc` redirects to `error.log` without applying `log4j` formatting pattern.

Is it possible or should I run the app without `jsvc` wrapper like

```
nohup java -jar /opt/myapp/myapp.jar &
```

or is there better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself. Just set default [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) at the beginning of your code entry point

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class App {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> logger.error(null, e));
    }

}
```

`log4j.properties`

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/opt/myapp/myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %m%n

# SMTP 
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=yoursmtp.example.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=youuser@yoursmtp.example.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=yourpassword
log4j.appender.email.From=youuser@yoursmtp.example.com
log4j.appender.email.To=youremail@example.com
log4j.appender.email.Subject=An error has happened
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.email.Threshold = ERROR
```