# Sending email on error occurance in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, email, logging, log4j

I want to sent error message as email whenever error occurs.

I know it is possible using configuration file of log4j.I want to sent mail using log4j using properties file for setting the properties instead of a xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SMTPAppender to send emails using log4j. See a list of properties here on this page:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

The following question has a full solution on how to use log4j SMTPAppender.

[Using log4j to send email reports via the SMTPAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306212/using-log4j-to-send-email-reports-via-the-smtpappender)