# log4j SMTPAppender, how to email only specific errors

Tags: java, email, log4j, smtpappender

I've configured an SMTPAppender in my JBoss server.

```
<appender name="SMTP" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender"> 
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
    <param name="To" value="steve.bucciacchio@muhc.mcgill.ca"/>
    <param name="From" value="jboss.wnetvmap47@muhc.mcgill.ca"/>
    <param name="Subject" value="PQDSN Sever Error on WNETVMAP47"/>
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="smtpout.muhc.mcgill.ca"/>
    <param name="BufferSize" value="512"/>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE},%c{1}] %m%n"/>
    </layout> 
</appender>
```

It works, I get emails every time an error is logged in JBoss's server.log file. The problem is that I get an email for every single error that is logged, even if the error was a JBoss error, has nothing to do with my application. Is there a way to select or filter what errors are emailed? Also can I email only errors that are logged to my application's log file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579503/with-smtpappender-i-receive-only-error-and-not-info-type-of-log-items
it maybe helpful