# Alternative for hoptoad in Java

Tags: java, email, notifications, hoptoad

I am looking for alternative for hoptoad in Java. I have tried to use the Java and Hoptoad but it doen not work many times. for example now it is not working in our Prod environment but it works everywhere else.

My requirement is to have one notifier that could be integrated with my log 4j file and that could send me error exception or error via mail to me.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, dont know if I get it right ! but you want that your app send you emails when some error happened right?! you can use the [SMTPAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html) from log4j.

here are some tutorials:

http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/java/sending-email-using-apache-log4j
[What is the proper way to configure SMTPAppender in log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778439/what-is-the-proper-way-to-configure-smtpappender-in-log4j)